# jquery autocomplete with submit action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a form with one input autocomplete, i would send the action only the user select one row in my input. 
I have write this code but not work submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#q").autocomplete({
    source: "tagSearch.php",
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 0,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
            $("#q").val(ui.item.label);

    $('#my-form').submit(function() {
        if($("#q").val() == "" || $("#q").val() == "no result" ){
           alert("Message Cannot be empty");
           return false;
        }
            return true;
    });

    }
  });                   
});     


<form id="my-form" action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input name="q" id="q" />
    <input type="submit" name="GO" value="GO" />        
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling `submit` on your select method but attaching a handler to the form.
Try with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#q").autocomplete({
        source: "tagSearch.php",
        minLength: 2,
        delay: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) { 
            $("#q").val(ui.item.label);
            $('#my-form').submit();
    });

    $('#my-form').submit(function() {
        if($("#q").val() == "" || $("#q").val() == "Nessun risultato" ){
           alert("Message Cannot be empty");
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

I moved the submit handler outside the select method. Now, inside select, just call submit and the proper handler will be executed

```
$('#my-form').submit();
```

Comment: Maybe explain the difference so the OP understands why? How you separated the autocomplete and submit calls and why...

Comment: @ianpgall: he was not calling submit, he was attaching a handler to it inside the select method.

Comment: I understand why, but I'm saying explain it in your post for the OP with a little detail (I know you've updated it a little now)

Comment: Thk for the solution, if i touch "enter" keyboard the submit works ,also without select row autocomplete. Why?

Comment: @Titanplus: add a `debugger;` instruction inside the submit handler. That will allow you to see what's going on.

Comment: i have try, pratically i would block submit when the user not selected one row in autocomplete input. i would block free enter words How make?

Comment: @Titan plus: if you have tried, what do you see when you break on the debugger? why the if condition is not met? Give me some info to work with